# Create a text area and analyze button

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on my college homework. I am having a lot of difficulty with it and getting stuck. My class mates are not helping me and the instructor hasn't responded. I am hoping I might get some help/understanding here. The current assignment I am working on and it is due today is:

Create a page containing a textarea and an “analyze” button. The results area will display the frequency of words of x characters. For example, the text “one two three” contains 2 3-character words and 1 5-character word. An improvement to the original design would be to strip out any extraneous characters that may skew the count.

I am just starting it now, so I will add the code here as I update. I know I won't have a problem with the HTML part, the JavaScript will be my problem. From what I get, I will need to have a function that counts the words and the characters in each word. But it needs to exclude spaces and characters like: ,.';/. I have not run across this code before, so any input on how I should frame the javascript will be helpful. Also it seems he wants me to list how many words have the same characters? am I reading this right?

My code thus far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <textarea id="txtarea">
    </textarea>
    <input type="button" id="analyze" value="Analyze" onclick="myFunction()" />

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <p id="wcnt"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var str = document.getElementById("txtarea").value;
            var res = str.split(/[\s\/\.;,\-0-9]/);
            var n = str.length;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "There are " + n + " characters in the text area.";
            for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {

                s = document.getElementById("txtarea").value;
                s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi, "");
                s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi, " ");
                s = s.replace(/\n /, "\n");
                document.getElementById("wcnt").innerHTML = "There are " + s.split(' ').length + " words in the text area.";
            }

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Now I need to figure out how to make it count the characters of each word then output how many words have x amount of characters. Such as 5 words have 4 characters and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you split up the question and google different parts of it, you'll be able to find the answer...it'd be more educational for you to learn and put it together yourself. The whole internet is an encyclopedia. We're happy to help if you are having issues with your code, but please try to code some of it first.

Comment: Hi Paige, I am coding, but figured I would ask here as well since I know I am going to get stuck. I plan on pasting my code here as I type it out and get advice, just letting others get an idea in their head first so when I start posting code they already know what I am trying to do. Trust me. I do not expect anyone to do my home work for me, just maybe point out where I may have a problem when I get it posted. =)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
    result = {}; // object Literal to hold  "word":NumberOfOccurrences

function analyzeFrequency() {

  // Match/extract words (accounting for apostrophes)
  var words = textarea.value.match(/[\w']+/g); // Array of words
  
  // Loop words Array
  for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
    var word = words[i];
    // Increment if exists OR assign value of 1
    result[word] = ++result[word] || 1; 
  }
  console.log( result );
}


analyzeFrequency(); // TODO: Do this on some button click
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea">
  I am working on my college-homework.
  Homework I am having a lot of difficulty with it and getting stuck.
  My class mates are not helping me and the instructor hasn't responded.
  I am hoping I might get some help/understanding here.
</textarea>
```

Notice how `Homework` and `homework` (lowercase) are registered as two different words, I'll leave it to you to fix that - if necessary and implement the `analyzeFrequency()` trigger on some button click.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you will have to use JavaScript's [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function with regex to define all the characters you do not want to include. Then loop through the resulting array and count the characters in each word.

```js
var words = document.getElementById("words");
var analyze = document.getElementById("analyze");

analyze.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var str = words.value;
    var res = str.split(/[\s\/\.;,\-0-9]/);
    for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
      alert(res[i].length);
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea id="words">This is a test of this word counter thing.</textarea>
<br/>
<button id="analyze">
   Analyze
</button>
```

Comment: Ok, so what I get from reading this is the str.split is removing anything that is not a word so it just counts the word. the next part loops through each word and counts the characters in the word?

Answer (score 0):

Your instructor does NOT want you to list how may words have the same characters but rather the same number of characters. The basic algorithm:

1. Assign the value of the text area to a variable.
2. Convert that string value into an array.  In javascript this could be accomplished with the String split method using a regular expression containing a character class.
3. Iterate over that array examining each element for its length. For each element, increment a counting object's property whose property name is the length of the element.
4. Iterate over the counting object's property list. Output to the result area each property name and its value.